# Store numbers as a string

Tags: c

I'm new in programming and I'm facing the problem where the program has to ask the user to enter as much numbers as he wants and store them in a variable, then print all the digits until a 0 is found.
The only thing i could think of was to store the scanf() in a char*, then try to print all digits until a 0 is found, but i end up with a segmentation faults...
here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    char entry[50];

    printf("Enter a number !\n");
    scanf("%c", &entry);    // maybe %d or %s ?
    printf("\n");
    int i=0;
    while (entry[i] != 0){

        if (entry[i] !=0){
        printf("%c", entry[i] );    // maybe %d with, (int)entry[i] ?
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit : It works now, had to fix `(entry[i] != 0)` --> `(entry[i] != '0')` and the scanf's `%c` --> `%s`.

Comment: Is it supposed to print all _digits_ until a zero, or all _numbers_ until a zero? Can you show an example of what the input and output should be?

Comment: You need to use `%s` to read a string, `%c` is for a single character.

Comment: `if (entry[i] !=0){` --> `... != '0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read it as string (%s) and compare until the current character is character 0:

```
while (entry[i] != '0') {
```

Characters go between single quotes in c.

You could get the same result comparing with the integer 48 as 48 is the ASCII code of 0 and it's how the char is stored internally but it's more readable and easy to understand comparing it to '0'.

And that if inside the while is not necessary as it's going to be always true.